# SQL Server 2005 - Please make sure SQL Server Agent service is running on the database server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Trying to do a fresh install of vmware's vcenter 4 and I get the following message when entering the db credentials. I've tried both sql and windows authentication, same thing. Trying this on SQL 2005. When I test connectivity through the DSN it connects with no problems at all.

I checked the sql server and the agent is definitely running. Maybe there is something I'm missing on the SQL Server configuration.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks.

Thanks!

Image of error can be seen here:

http://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/1302418-25209/vcenter.JPG

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the install media again. Must have been a bug in the software. Working okay now.